# Replace text in files by variable values using Bash

Tags: bash

I have php files with the flag like `/* TEST */`.

In the script, I have variables with this flag and the value to replace:

```
test="defined('_TEST') or die('Test test');"
testPattern="/* TEST */"
```

My code returns no errors, but flags aren't replaced:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i -e 's/"$testPattern"/"$test"/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed string is in single quotes. Variable expansion does not occur there. Switch to double quotes:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i -e "s/$testPattern/$test/g" {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this case I get errors: sed: 1: "s//* TEST *//defined('_J ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Comment: You have to adjust the pattern to be properly escaped, otherwise, `sed` is interpreting it according its rules. In particular, you should escape the characters with special meaning for `sed`, the slash and the start of `$testPattern`.

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

Try this one:

```
sed -i '' "s~$testPattern~$test~g" $(find . -name '*.php')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it also doesn't replace.

Comment: Can you check the latest edit?
on MacOS the -i flag requires a specified extension following the flag, in this case `''`.  (If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved)

Comment: Yes. I've checked this the last edit. The same result.